# Could SUSPEND work on Ubuntu with AMD Ryzen 5 4500U + Radeon graphics?

Tags: suspend

Long time Linux user here who knows only the basics!

My go-to Linux OS is up and running on my new Asus S15 Vivobook, AMD Ryzen 4500U, Radeon graphics.

Only problem is, suspend does not actually suspend the system, and battery drains as usual.

Suspend is an essential part of my work flow, hence my continued quest to see if I can solve the issue. So far, no luck. I tested some other distros and suspend does not shut down the machine properly (though I tested via usb installation media).

I have confirmed that this is not fixable with my current OS via a 43 post forum process.

I have turned up here because I found this https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

**Does anyone think that installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, and then doing the AMD Radeon software update, would get suspend working on my laptop?**

I'm doubtful - I don't think my issue is with Radeon, I think it is with the Ryzen 4500U processor.

I found the linked page, became excited and downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 and planned to install it and do the AMD software update process, but then realised it's specifically for AMD graphics, which might mean that the suspend issue will remain unchanged.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Here are my laptop's specs:

```
System:    Host: <filter> Kernel: 5.9.0-4mx-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A 
           parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-4mx-amd64 
           root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor 
           "acpi_osi=!Windows 2013" "acpi_osi=!Windows 2012" 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.5 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM 1.26.0 
           Distro: MX-19.3_ahs_x64 patito feo November 11  2020 
           base: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X521IA_M533IA v: 1.0 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X521IA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: X521IA.303 date: 07/31/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 18.8 Wh condition: 50.9/50.0 Wh (102%) volts: 11.9/11.9 
           model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
           cycles: 4 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 type: MCP 
           arch: Zen family: 17 (23) model-id: 60 (96) stepping: 1 microcode: 8600106 
           L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 28444 
           Speed: 1397 MHz min/max: 1400/2375 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1397 
           2: 1397 3: 1397 4: 1340 5: 1385 6: 1397 
           Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected 
           Type: l1tf status: Not affected 
           Type: mds status: Not affected 
           Type: meltdown status: Not affected 
           Type: spec_store_bypass 
           mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
           Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
           Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full AMD retpoline, IBPB: conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP: 
           disabled, RSB filling 
           Type: srbds status: Not affected 
           Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
           chip ID: 1002:1636 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.39.0 5.9.0-4mx-amd64 LLVM 10.0.0) 
           v: 4.6 Mesa 20.1.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.1 chip ID: 1002:1637 
           Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 03:00.6 chip ID: 1022:15e3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.9.0-4mx-amd64 
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
           chip ID: 8086:2723 
           IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 12.94 GiB (5.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: HFM256GDJTNG-8310A size: 238.47 GiB 
           block size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 15.8 Gb/s lanes: 2 serial: <filter> 
           rev: 80001C00 scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / raw size: 198.78 GiB size: 194.66 GiB (97.93%) used: 12.94 GiB (6.6%) 
           fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 34.8 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 34 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-stable-updates.list 
           1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list 
           1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
           2: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mx.list 
           1: deb https://ftp.saix.net/pub/linux/distributions/mxlinux/mx/repo/ buster main non-free
           2: deb https://ftp.saix.net/pub/linux/distributions/mxlinux/mx/testrepo/ buster test
           3: deb https://ftp.saix.net/pub/linux/distributions/mxlinux/mx/repo/ buster ahs
           No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/various.list 
Info:      Processes: 293 Uptime: 4h 03m Memory: 7.27 GiB used: 4.35 GiB (59.8%) Init: SysVinit 
           v: 2.93 runlevel: 5 default: 5 Compilers: gcc: 8.3.0 alt: 8 Shell: quick-system-in 
           running in: quick-system-in inxi: 3.0.36
```

Comment: It seems like you're asking if suspend works on Ubuntu.  I don't see why it wouldn't.  If you think your hardware has some anomaly, the only way to know if it has this problem on Ubuntu is to install Ubuntu. Since MX Linux is not on topic, we can't help with your current OS, but you could ask on Unix&Linux.  Once you have installed Ubuntu, if you have issues, provide details about your issue with Ubuntu so we can help with that.

Comment: No, I am definitely not asking if suspend works on Ubuntu. Suspend worked on several Linux distros that enjoyed on older laptops. But suspend seems to be a problem with the listed hardware. My question is, "could suspend work on Ubuntu with AMD Ryzen 5 4500U + Radeon graphics?", and I am asking before I try installing so that I don't have to spend more time and effort with a new installation that may not work. My question is justified by the fact that only a handful of distros are listed at the AMD Radeon link I shared, and I am trying to clarify if the software upgrade will do the trick.

Comment: What you mean to say is that you do not know the answer to the question. Fine. But if you don't know the answer to a question, don't waste a person's time with an indirect way of saying you don't know.